# Socket.js inside controllers in server(Node.js)

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am on the process of building a chat application with nodejs, reactjs mongo and socket.io.My chat app consists of both one to one and group chats.I have built a schema for group chat and i am inserting group names along with its members and their chats in the table.Since im a beginner towards socket.io, I dont know where to put the socket logic that needs to be fired after the db post operation.Can some one suggest any examples for me?

Comment: Sure thing, check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code accordingly:

=> **server.js** file

```
    // Declare socket.io
    const io = require('socket.io')(server);

    // Add middleware to set socket.io in 
    app.use((req, res, next)=>{ res.locals['socketio'] = io; next(); });
```

=> In your **controller** file

```
    // Get the value of socket.io
    module.exports = your_function_name =  (req, res) => {

    const io = res.locals['socketio']
    // Use io when you need.

    });
```

Hope this solves your query.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate you socket related code by following way :

**==>app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var socket = require('./socketServer');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen((config.node_port || 3000), function () {
    console.log('Listening on port ' + (config.node_port || 3000) + '...');
});
socket.socketStartUp(server);
module.exports = app;
```

**==>socketServer.js**

```
var io = require('socket.io')();
var socketFunction = {}
socketFunction.socketStartUp = function (server) {
    io.attach(server);
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log("New user is connected with socket:", socket.id);
    })
}
module.exports = socketFunction;
```

You can also check node API startup code with socket functionality in below link:

[Node API Start up](https://github.com/mim-narola/node_api_startup)

Hope this answer is helpful to you